# Android preferenceFragment doesn't display nothing and menu remain selected

Tags: android

I'm tryng study the Preference system of Android.

When from my navdrawer I call settings fragment, it doesn't show nothing and menu remain selected, also if I select another voice.

This is the screen at startup of my APP:

[image]

Where all is perfect. After I click on Impostazioni (settings, in English), Home (or the "Elenca" item) reamin checked, also with "Impostazioni"

[image]

Another one problem is that Settings frame is blank (no error in Log but it's all blank).

This is XML preferences.xml stored under res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_sms_storage_title"
        android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="pref_sync"
            android:title="@string/pref_sync"
            android:summary="@string/pref_sync_summ"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is my Settings Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.xxxxxx.R;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new InnerSettingsFragment();
    }

    public static class InnerSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally this is my BaseApp that mantains the navdrawer logic:

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();


                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {




                    case R.id.home:

                        DashboardFragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, dashboardFragment,"DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT");
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.list_event:
                        ListEventFragment fragmentListEvent = new ListEventFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragmentListEvent);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;

                    case R.id.settings:
                        SettingsFragment fragmentSettings = new SettingsFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragmentSettings);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;






                    default:

                        return true;

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't make your `PreferenceFragment` an *inner class*, add your *outer class* in its place, and still expect things to work as usual. It won't because the *outer* `onCreate()` wouldn't delegate to the *inner* `onCreate()` by itself. So, just make your `InnerSettingsFragment` a regular top-level class and you'll start seeing your preferences get loaded from the XML resource.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, it works, but I have the problem that double items are checked at same time... I'm going to edit my question. Thank you!

Comment: Found what code is giving me the issue. I'll open new question, very different. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Do post a link here. I'll take a look in the morning in case nobody answers.

Comment: This is new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254626/android-issue-with-menu-item-that-are-multiple-checked Have a nice day ;-)